# how to correctly configure react-transition-group to independently animate nested animations?

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I have added a nested route to the official React Router transition example.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-animated-transitions-lihls?file=/example.js

I have used the default fade example on the outer switch and a "zoom" transition the nested switch but both switches are both fade aninmated. i.e. the outer animation is overriding the nested animation which has no effect. The zoom effect css is works as expected if i place it on the parent route.

```
function AnimationApp() {
  return (
  ...
  <CSSTransition key={location.key} classNames="fade" timeout={500}>
    <Switch location={location}>
  ...
  );
}

function Nested() {
  return (
  ...
  <CSSTransition key={location.key} classNames="zoom" timeout={500}>
    <Switch location={location}>
    ...
  );
}
```

Ive also tried wrapping the nested csstransition in a transition group but the error is the same.

```
  <TransitionGroup>
    <CSSTransition key={location.key} classNames="zoom" timeout={500}>
      <Switch location={location}>
      ...
```

Am I doing something wrong or does react-transition-group not support nested routes?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have forked a solution adding a key to the component state independent of the routers location object and updating it on link clicks. Its not the prettiest solution (adding onclick to all the links) and there's a bit of repetition. If there is a way in React to say "add an onClick to all NavLinks" that would be better.

quick summary of changes...

```
  let [key, setKey] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    setKey(Math.random());
  }, []);
  ...
  <NavLink onClick={() => setKey(Math.random)} to={`${url}/child1`}>
     Child1
  </NavLink>
  ...
  <TransitionGroup>
    <CSSTransition>
      <Route path={`${url}/child1`} children={<Child1 />} />
  ...
```

It will work for any level in a component tree to allow independent CSSTransitions. The principal is sound and makes more sense than using the location.pathname for a key for multilevel components but it needs a bit of tidying up.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-animated-transitions-using-state-and-effects-x3v3k?file=/example.js